# Do I need a multiple-entry visa for an intra-Schengen layover?

Tags: visas, schengen, transit

I plan to visit Spain and Portugal very soon, and I have received a single-entry Schengen Visa.

I will travel from Spain to Portugal on TAP airlines, which is a domestic flight between Schengen countries.

My question is, upon departure from Portugal, I will be going to a non-Schengen country (Cairo), but I have a layover in Germany which is a Schengen Country. Will I still be able to enter Germany even if I have departed Portugal to a non-Schengen destination?

Comment: You'll be exiting the Schengen area in Germany, not in Portugal.

Comment: @JoErNanO There isn't much more to say on the topic, you could make that an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you travel Portugal - Germany - Egypt, you will stay in the Schengen area till you leave Germany, you will have an internal Schengen area flight and get out of the Schengen area when you leave Germany.

If your layover is long enough you can leave the airport. For most European airports they advise not to leave the airport if your stop is less than 5 hours, but it does differ between the different airports.

On the other hand, if you fly from Portugal to Egypt and then to Germany, you would have left the Schengen area when leaving Portugal and would not be allowed into Germany, as your visit would be a second entry into the Schengen area.

Comment: I appreciate the response, but just to avoid the confusion, i will be departing from Lisbon - Destination Egypt and not Germany. Will that make a difference? i have a 12 hour layover.

Comment: It does not make difference what your final destination is, if the stop in Germany is before you go to Egypt, you can get out of the airport. If you go to Egypt before you go to Germany it is not the same trip and you would need to have a multiple entrance or new visa.

Comment: @AmrSaid your flight from Portugal to Germany is an "internal" Schengen flight -- essentially like a domestic flight as far as immigration controls.  Other people on the plane might be staying in Germany or continuing to another Schengen country.  Therefore, *everyone* on the plane is "inside" the Schengen area, including you, which is why you *will not* go through exit controls when you leave Portugal, and you *will* go through them when you leave Germany.